# Mysql Update query optimize for single table

Tags: java, mysql, database-administration

I am using MySql database for my Project,

I have one table having **6 Millions records**, Out of which I am updating around **5 Millions records**, my table structure and query are as below.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `ref_id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_id_2` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dna_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ref_id_1`,`ref_id_2`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `dna_id` (`dna_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Update Query

```
UPDATE temp SET dna_id = 8 WHERE product_id ='Dr_23' AND ref_id_1 = 4;
```

There are **5 Million** records for Product Id **Dr_23**

Above query taking around 2 minutes to execute. I have 32 GB RAM and SSD Harddisk.

Does anyone know how to optimize this query

Comment: Add `dna_id != 8` to your `where` clause. Use the SQL command `explain <query>` to see if the indices are used. If not add another index like `KEY combined(product_id, ref_id_1, dna_id)`.

Comment: Indices probably won't make a big difference if 5 millions out of 6 million rows must be updated anyway.

Comment: Also some kind of index that combines the columns used in the WHERE section together could help. If the index contains `product_id`, `ref_id_1` and `dna_id`, then you only need to look in the index to find what to update.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE temp  ADD INDEX (ref_id_1,product_id)` is your best chance of improvement

Comment: I have just added the table for testing purpose, my actual table already contains around 5 -6 indexes, And I don't think that adding more indexes is a good idea.